# Scrollable Selected Item Text in Spinner Android

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

Its second day and struggle still continues... :(
I have one spinner where in there are itemms with huge text length.. so i wanted to add eclippse and marque.so that selected item will get scrollable..

need the selected item of a spinner to scroll after being selected. The width of the spinner is smaller than the text of its choices. Whenever an item is selected, it has to scroll indefinitely in the spinner display. I can get text in a TextView to marquee, but not the text of the spinner selected item. Any clue?

I have 
Spinner

```
private Spinner spinProcess;

spinProcess = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinSearch);
```

and XMl for this spinner is as below

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinSearch"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/add_project_drop_down_enabled"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="35dp"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:textColor="@color/spinnerText" />
```

And adapter for sinner is as below

```
final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HelpActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            for(int i=0;i<SpinnerLIst.size();i++)
            {
                arrayAdapter.add(SpinnerLIst.get(i));
            }

            spinProcess.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

i tried modifying android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item  ..but none worked for me??
there are lot of question already been asked regarding this.. but no such solution worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with custom adapter for spinner

item_row.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
        android:lines="1"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text"
        android:textColor="#ff4500" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adapter:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> albumData;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<String> albumList) {
        mContext = context;
        albumData = albumList;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return albumData.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {

        private TextView albumName;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.albumName = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.albumName.setText(albumData.get(position));
            holder.albumName.setSelected(true);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Spinner spin;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo2);
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinSearch);
        mContext = this;

        List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();

        item.add("Item 1");
        item.add("Item 1 setAnimationListener setAnimationListener setAnimationListener item 1");

        SpinnerAdapter adapter = new SpinnerAdapter(mContext, item);

        spin.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: it is working..when i select item from drop down..the one with large text scroll..

Comment: what i am looking is...selected item in spinner list should be scrollable.. i had tried this thing...it only scroll text in list items not the selected one

Comment: selected one...dat means the one which is shown on spinner..it does that..the selected item on spinner scrolls..

Comment: not working at my end..could you please mail me your sample app @    er.vicky1989@gmail.com

Comment: na :(  did you mailed me?

Comment: get my code from here http://www.codeshare.io/bDPev ...i can't mail you right now..

Comment: 3 purple baloons pooping out dere..nothing else on that link

Comment: try once more..link may not be active..now it is

Comment: i mailed u the code..i ws working on some other task..i have edited it to get it worked for you..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63790/discussion-between-mr-vicky-and-meenal-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Its also working at my end.
Answer provided my Meenal Sharma is working for me.
Important point is to add RelativeLayout and Instead of using

```
android:lines="1"
android:singleLine="true"
```

And Layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
     <CheckedTextView
          android:id="@+id/textView"
          style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:textSize="19sp"
          android:paddingLeft="1dp"
          android:scrollHorizontally="true"
          android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
          android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```